# Why is freeimagehosting.net blocked, and when did it start being blocked?

Tags: support, edits, filtering

I just made [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/763408/revisions) and the system initially refused it because the body contained a reference to `freeimagehosting.net`. What's up?

Comment: Then don't use that location. Use the editor to upload the image to imgur.

Comment: Known malware location; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159513/135736

Comment: @gunr2171 it's not me, it's the OP. I was only editing it.

Comment: @Wooble, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Charles: but the system won't let me downvote myself, and I like to downvote link-only answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On December 20, 2012, [the malware detection service used by Google Chrome started alerting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159512/1358870) when presented with images from `freeimagehosting.net`.

As a result, [URLs from that domain were added to the post body blacklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159513/135887).  The blacklist [was made network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159675/can-we-please-block-malware-if-possible#comment462698_159689) later that day.

The post you edited was created before the blacklist was put in place.  This is basically the same problem encountered with "problem" in historic question titles.